# Those ads carousel are try to tell me something

Tags: support, advertising

#### Disclaimer : all links are NSFW.

I was browsing physics.SE And I noticed a pattern in the ads carousel.

It started with a Pillow ads then it escalated quickly :
A pillow ads

> [image]

Sex performance Ads

> [image]

Sex improvement drugs

> [image]

The carousel was fast I just had the time to get the link before it switch.
At the end I was a bit shook but it's ok. Next add will help:
A treatments to manage or stop my hallucinations

> [image: treatments to manage or stop my hallucinations]

Comment: Worse, the second one is animated!

Answer (score -4, accepted):

This is being addressed immediately.  Thank you for flagging.

Comment: Really you guys should get a VM with a french Windows. I make daily reports, on case I collect in less than 10 minutes. This one was longer as the ads keeps changing for something fun.

Comment: I heard that before... and as you can see, whatever you do to "address this" ***has no effect*** on future ads, where "future" is even couple of hours from this time. Sorry, but this is plain useless.

Comment: @ShadowTheCoffeeWizard sorry you feel that way.  However, I still appreciate your feedback.  Have a wonderful day.

Comment: As a side note - I do appreciate the [staff] pin in user profiles, but perhaps it would be nice to have one of those in post cards, too

Comment: @TerryGuyton-Bradley to make it clear, nothing personal here. You do your job just fine and I admire that. Problem is in the top levels who decide to work with problematic ad providers.

Comment: What I want to know is *how* this happened. Was a moderator asleep at the console when these ads came in for approval? Did SE get hacked by a rogue advertiser?

Comment: @RobertColumbia most likely outsourcing to a dubious party. Anyways it confirmed my believes that the french are always up to dubious practices, even at work ;)

Comment: @ShadowTheCoffeeWizard, while I also experienced this "frustration". About 6 hours after this post, All bad ads where removed. Only ads now are either IBM/Microsoft or StackOverflow related

Comment: @xdtTransform well for me it's deeper than just frustration. It's disappointment, and disbelief in the decisions made by SE.